# How to Sum all instances of a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

these are my models

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Language = models.IntegerField()
    Population = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class World(models.Model):
    Languages_spoken = model.Charfield(max_length=12000)
    World_population = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am trying to add `Population` of all instances in `Countries` to sum and show on `World_population` field on class `World`

What I have tried

```
class World(models.Model):
    Languages_spoken = model.Charfield(max_length=12000)
    World_population = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.World_population = Countries.objects.get(Population) # I know this is not correct
        super(World,self).save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Countries.objects.aggregate(total_population=Sum('Population'))
```

More info on aggregation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sum() here,

```
self.World_population = Countries.objects.aggregate(Sum('Population'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/